# Getting Error in Share to Instagram iOS Objective C

Tags: objective-c, instagram, ios11

I want to share a single image to Instagram "image.png" Is this an iOS 11 error?

I'm getting this error:

```
Couldn't get file size for file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/492BF71E-E579-4792-8BE9-144D9C1EC73D/Documents/insta.igo -- file:///: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “insta.igo” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/492BF71E-E579-4792-8BE9-144D9C1EC73D/Documents/insta.igo -- file:///, NSFilePath=/file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/492BF71E-E579-4792-8BE9-144D9C1EC73D/Documents/insta.igo, NSUnderlyingError=0x1cc054760 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

Here's the code

```
-(void)shareInInstagram{
  UIImage *imge = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
  NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imge); //convert image into .png format.
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
  NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]]; //add our image to the path
  [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)
  NSLog(@"image saved");


  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 , 0, 0, 0);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
  [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  NSString *fileNameToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/insta.igo"];
  NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameToSave];
  NSLog(@"jpg path %@",jpgPath);
  NSString *newJpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath]; //[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath] ];
  NSLog(@"with File path %@",newJpgPath);
  NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:newJpgPath];
  NSLog(@"url Path %@",igImageHookFile);

  self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
  self.dic = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
  self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
  [self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];


}
```

Comment: `NSString *newJpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath];` Bad idea. Try instead `NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:jpgPath];`?

Answer (score 0):

This code works in my app.

```
GRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
UIImage *image = [self getImageToShare];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); //convert image into .png format.
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
NSString *jpgPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]]; //add our image to the path
[fileManager createFileAtPath:jpgPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)


NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@", jpgPath]];
self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
self.documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
self.documentController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
[self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView: self.view animated: YES ];
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://media?id=MEDIA_ID"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES ];
}else{
    [self showMessage:@"No Instagram Found"];
}
```

Comment: From the documentation, MEDIA_ID is supposed to be the id of a post the app will show when opened. Not used for sharing new content.